# FPS drop in FFMPEG streaming processes to FB from production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I have made a rails app that can stream live videos to facebook rtmp server and deployed it on AWS. I have used nginx as web server. The major problem that I am encountering after viewing log files of FFMpeg processes is that sometimes the FPS of FFmpeg process  starts to drop. In some cases, it remains stable at 25 FPS but in some cases, it remains at 25 only for sometime, and after that it starts to drop and sometimes it falls to even 3-4 FPS which is unacceptable during live streaming. As FFMpeg process is quite heavy, I would also like to share my CPU info as well.

CPU information is:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 2400.070
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm xsaveopt fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4800.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:`

FFMPEG log file with unstable fps: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1gtp1iXJppkUndFamk4M0lRYzA

FFMPEG log file with stable fps: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1gtp1iXJppkMkVCZEJjYWJrVTA

When FPS was stable, I also tried to run another parallel FFMpeg process from the same server which resulted in FPS dropping of both the processes to 13-14 FPS.

I am currently using this FFMPEG command:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -re -y -f image2 -i "image_path" -i "audio_path.aac" -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v high -s 1280x720 -vb 400k -maxrate 400k -minrate 400k -bufsize 600k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -t 14400 -strict -2 -f flv "rtmp_server_link"`

I never face this problem when I try to stream to FB using app on my localhost.

So, my questions are:

1. What can be the reason for this FPS drop?
2. Can upscaling production server help me fix this issue?
3. Can I run multiple FFMpeg processes for streaming from same server without performance drop?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with Rails, and doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow.  It's a SuperUser question, but I went ahead and answered it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only getting 25 FPS, your machine isn't keeping up.  You've set the output to 30 FPS, and that's what it should be set to for Facebook Live.

Your CPU spec isn't as relevant as what `top` shows you when you're running this script.  I bet you'll see your loadavg high, and CPU utilization maxed out.

Furthermore, your bitrate is extremely low for 720p video, but I'm guessing you can get away with this due to having a single static image.  You might consider turning up your maximum bitrate though to accommodate the keyframe.  And, you can use a 2-second keyframe interval, instead of 1.

Comment: The OP's set a KF interval of 1 second: `-g 30`

Comment: So, this basically means that upgrading the specs of CPU can help me to fix the issue?

Comment: Sure, but try reducing g to `60` first.

Comment: @AakashGupta It means you need to provide more information and confirm that CPU is an issue.

Comment: should I also add the output of top command while ffmpeg process is on?